# Uubntu 18.04 fails to boot with error: r8169 can't disable aspm; OS doesn't have ASPM control

Tags: boot, 18.04

What can I do? I see others have this error but it doesn't prevent booting. Asus E402M laptop.

It was working fine until a recent kernel update (58) and the latest kernel (60) also doesn't boot.

Very annoying...

Comment: The ASPM message might not be related to the reason your laptop stops booting, it just might be the last thing printed during the boot process. Are you able to switch to a virtual terminal via CTRL+ALT+F4 or similar (meaning the system has started but your graphics are not running)

Comment: No, I can't switch to a virtual terminal but I can boot with a previous kernel. There is no record in var/log/syslog of the failed boot. Where will I find that information? I seem to be the only person with this problem or perhaps the only person left using Ubuntu!

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and the original kernel boots fine but the latest kernel does not boot.